# Delphi TadoTable Locate

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have MsAccess table with the following fields:
1. Billing Type
2. Billing Code
3. Description - memo type.

I also have an Edit box named srch

I would like to search the filed Description and find the first record that has the search sting. This is what I try to use:

```
billingcode.Locate('Description',srch.Text,[loPartialKey]) ;
```

I get error 'Sort order can not be applied"

any ideas how to fix that ?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Figure it out, LOCATE can not be used with Memo field, I used FILTER instead like this:

```
billingcode.Filter :='Description LIKE '+QuotedSTR('%'+srch.text+'%');
```

much better.

Comment: I thought the answer was obvious that LOCATE can not be used for memo. I should have been more precise than fast.

Comment: More importantly, Locate only looks at the first characters, so you couldn't use it for a text search even on a VARCHAR field. I mean `Locate('FLDNAME','foo',[loPartialKey])` will find a record with value `foo 123` but not values like `Test foo 123`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Locate` to search a `Blobfield` like a Memo.

Workarounds for locating could be

-selecting an additional casted field only for searching (using TAdoDataset instead of TAdoTable)

```
SELECT *
,LEFT( Description,8000) as Help4Search  -- Access syntax
--,Cast(Description as Varchar(8000)) as Help4Search --example SQL-Server syntax
FROM YourTable;
```

-stepping through the dataset with disabled controls, using delphi `POS`